# Gitlab-CI. Limit parallel jobs in one stage to specific amount

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

i need to limit the amount of parallel jobs because they depend on an external service that only has N available slots for building, but i have more than N jobs in the gitlab pipeline, so i wanted a way to limit the amount of parallels in the job to be equal to N.

Basically:

```
-I have 1 stage with 3 parallel jobs.
    (it has to be only one stage)
-Each job depends on an external building service (outside of gitlab) and it has 2 parallel "slots".
    (i cannot raise the number of slots in the external service)
-I need to run the 3 parallel jobs, but no more than 2 always, for them not to fail due to not available slots in the external service.
    (independent of the other ones success or failed status)
```

I already read the documentation about "needs" but i don't find a way to run the next job even if the "needed" job fails.

Also i read the documentation for "rules" but i don't understand if by rules i can check the number of parallel jobs that are running for the current stage.

Thanks

Comment: Why not putting all together in one job? I know, that is not fancy at all ... but thus you can handle your bottleneck. And it would be the simplest solution.

Comment: Is it a limit of 2 parallel slots "per pipeline" or global? So if you have 2 parallel pipelines running, can you still run only 2 of those jobs, or  2 jobs x 2 pipelines=4 jobs?

Comment: @Sandman i don't understand, you mean, different stages inside a job? it has to be only on stage as requirement

Comment: @JakubMatczak hi! yes, its global